# If partner opens one heart, what do I need to respond with one spade?

Tags: bridge, bidding, openings

If my partner opens one heart, and I respond one spade, am I showing four or five spades?

Answer (score 3):

In Standard American bidding (and 2/1 game forcing for that matter), after partner's 1H opening, 1S promises at least 4 spades. After 1H-1S, partner's mostly likely calls are 1NT (5332 shape with no more than 14 HCP), 2 of a minor (5-4 or better in the bid suits, may have anything short of a game force in terms of values), 2H (6+ hearts, probably less than 17 high card points), 2NT (18-19 HCP, 5332 shape), or some number of spades.

After 1H-1S-1NT, your rebids:

- 2H: This is a tough one. Probably 5 spades, a doubleton heart honor, and shortness in one of the minors. You're taking the position that playing 2H in a 5-2 fit is better than playing 1NT (if you had 3 hearts and a weak hand, you shouldn't have bothered to show spades).
- 2S: The 2S rebid shows a weak hand, usually with 6+ spades (though it could be an exceptionally weak hand with shortness somewhere and only 5 spades, e.g. Qxxxx x Kxx xxxx, which rates to take 0-1 tricks at NT but a few tricks with spades as trumps).
- 2NT: Invitational values, likely exactly 4 spades and 2 hearts.
- 3NT: Game forcing values, likely exactly 4 spades and 2 hearts.
- 2m: You should have a discussion with your partners about this auction, but SAYC says this should be non-forcing and natural.
- 3H: 3-card heart support, invitational values.
- pass: any weakish hand not covered above.

After 1H-1S-2m:

- Pass: A weak hand with 3- or 4-card support for the minor and usually a singleton or void in hearts.
- 2H: A weak hand, virtually guaranteed to have a heart doubleton (again, with 3-card support, why not raise hearts in the first place?)
- 2S: Shows 6 spades or better (or, more rarely, a weak 5-5 in spades and the unbid minor with a singleton heart). With other shapes and a weak hand, correct to 2H with a doubleton heart or pass partner's minor.
- 2NT: Balanced, invitational.
- 3m: 4-card support for the minor, invitational values.
- 3S: 6+ spades, invitational values
- The fourth suit at the cheapest level: forcing for one round, unable to make a natural bid at this point. Examples:

  - Interested in 3NT but unable to stop the unbid minor.
  - Interested in slam in one of partner's suits and thus unwilling to jump directly to game.
  - Interest in a spade slam but require more information from partner

After 1H-1S-2H:
 - 2S: This shows a weak hand with 6 spades or better and likely a heart void; why else correct from partner's 6-card suit to yours?

- 2NT: Natural, invitational.
- 3m: Natural and game forcing.
- 3H: Invitational with 3 hearts.

Obviously, this doesn't cover all the bases, but it lays out some of the most common situations.

Comment: **Don't rebid 5-card suits unless as a positive statement of strength**. You should know better @ruds, as your comments on Bridge are usually sensible.

Comment: Are you referring to 1H-1S-1NT-2S or 1H-1S-2m-2S? The first seems pretty sensible; without a doubleton spade, opener either has 6 hearts or a 4-card minor and so is not rebidding 1NT; therefore it is often reasonable to improve 1NT to 2S with a weak hand and 5 spades. As for a weak hand with 5=1=5=2 shape, 2D and 2NT are both stronger actions. Do you prefer a preference to 2S with that hand, or passing in a possible 4-2 fit? Anything you do could be wrong.

Comment: **Don't rebid a five ward suit with weakness.** Partner will take you for 6, **and is required to pass you with a void** unless she is strong. Would you rather play in a 4-2 or a 5-0? Remember that partner's 1H opening, even playing 4-card majors, will be 5 cards long more than 70% of the time.

Comment: Rebidding a 5-card suit with a weak hand is the undeniable sign of a novice, who has yet to grasp the true fundamentals of bidding. **Get over it**. Read the literature on any decent web site, like Richard Pavlicek's (http://www.rpbridge.net/bbtc.htm), if you don't believe me.

Comment: You are simply wrong about correcting the 1NT rebid back you your 5-card suit; partner certainly doesn't have a void. After 1h-1s-2m when you hold 5-5 in spades and the other minor and a stiff heart, any call you take could be right or wrong, but I take comfort in the fact that partner's most likely shape is 5422, and so at MPs I bid the major. At imps, you haven't been doubled yet, so probably pass is the best call.

Comment: PS, I'll note that http://www.rpbridge.net/2z09.htm recommends rebidding your suit with 5+ and 6-10 HCP after a 1NT rebid by responder. That page suggests passing 2m by omission (under an "all other weak hands preference" rubric), but none of his example hands address this frankly problematic hand type.

Answer (score 2):

You need only four spades to respond one spade.

When your partner opens, you are expected to try to keep the bidding open if possible.
That's why you need only four of a major to respond, and as little six points (although you may have a lot more). The fact that you have four spades is valuable information. Your bid (in a new suit) is forcing, meaning that you will get a chance to bid again and show your other values.

A small percentage of the time, partner will be 5-4 in hearts and spades, and be able to raise  spades, and you'll have a 4-4 fit.

More often, there will be a try for a no trump contract. Partner may bid no trump if spades is the only suit where s/he is short. If partner is 5-4 in hearts and a minor, the minor will be bid, and if you have the other minor, you can bid no trump.

Occasionally, you'll find a 4-4 fit in a minor, and make a part score. Game is unlikely unless you and partner have at least 28-29 points between you.

Answer (score -1):

One spade over one heart may indicate transfer to 1NT by opener as one spade may have weak hand with minimum 3 carder weak Spade. After 1NT rebid it is passed so that strong hand does not become dummy

Comment: If you are suggesting this as a convention, it is not really an answer since it needs to be agreed with partner beforehand. Or is there a system where this is normal?